# Restrict direct access to .php files through browser and allow only index.php to access them

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a script on my website allowing users to edit/create their account. I want to restrict direct access to the files through browser (ex.www.mydomain.com/cp/page/login.php or www.mydomain.com/cp/home.php) and allow only index.php to access these files. I tried with .htaccess but index.php cant access them. Also i can't move them out of public_html folder. Its not include folder. How i can achive that?
Please let me now if you need something else.

Comment: can you post your existing .htaccess code? using it is the correct way

Comment: So what URL would a user navigate to in order to do actions such as login?  Can you show your htaccess?

Comment: the url is www.mydomain.com/CP/index.php

`<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>`

Comment: By "allow only index.php to access them" do you mean allow the *actual script* to read them from the file system? Or do you mean the page that's loaded on the browser's end which *links* to other php URLs and is thus **referred to** by the index.php file?

Comment: To allow the script to read them from the file system

Answer (score 5):

One way of doing that is by using `include` or `require` calls from PHP:

```
include '/path/to/script.php';
```

`include` is handled by PHP on server side hence Apache blocks will not impact this.

Then you can keep your existing `<Files>` directives to block access to `.php` file:

```
<Files *.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files index.php>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Last seen 5 months ago. Doubt you're getting a green tick :(

Answer (score 2):

One common way in PHP is to define something in `index.php` and check for it in the others:

```
//index.php
define('INDEX', true);

if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
    if($_GET['page'] == 'home') {
        include('cp/home.php');
    }
}


//home.php
if(!defined('INDEX') { die(); }
//more code
```